# Объясните часть кода по django

Tags: python, django

Объясните что делает и как работает следующая строчка: `return Bb.objects.filter(rubric=self.kwargs['rubric_id'])`.
Спасибо.

Comment: Без знания происхождения каждого упомянутого здесь объекта ответить на этот вопрос не получится

Comment: @andreymal, я понимаю что возвращается набор записей из модели Bb у которых поле rubric равно указанному значению, то есть, `self.kwargs[rubric_id]`, но я не понимаю что означает это значение, как оно достается.

Comment: А это зависит от того, что такое self

Comment: @andreymal, `def get_queryset(self): 
return Bb.objects.filter(rubric=self.kwargs['rubric_id'])`

Comment: Понятнее не стало. Это метод какого-то класса?

Comment: @andreymal, да, класса-контроллера ListView

Comment: Про ListView и его self.kwargs тоже есть в документации https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display.html#dynamic-filtering

Answer (score 1):

```py
return Bb.objects.filter(rubric=self.kwargs['rubric_id'])
```

`Bd` - это так называемая model в django. Обычно соответсвтует таблице в БД.

`objects` - объект QuerySet, дает доступ к данным в таблицы Bd.

`filter(условие)` - данные из таблицы будут отфильтрованы по `условию`

`rubric=self.kwargs['rubric_id']` условие для фильтрации, где rubric является колонкой(полем) в таблице Bd, например `rubric=42`, записи будут отобраны из таблицы Bb, только для рубрики 42.

`self.kwargs` это просто словарь, который создала для Вас Django. Обычно выглядит примерно так - `{'rubric_id': 42}`, таким образом self.kwargs['rubric_id'] содержит значение 42.

Откуда взялось 42? Например можно вызвать Вашу функцию так - get_bd(rubric_id=42}) или так `get_bd(..., {'rubric_id': 42})`, возможно это делает Django автоматически, например через urls.py, или где то в коде.